# Communicating state to anonymous child components

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Still pretty new to react... I struggling understanding how to communicate something as simple as passing hover state down through components.  I'm using nextjs and styled-jsx.

With plain old CSS back in the day I could have written a selector like the following to change the text color of an element when its parent is hovered on.

```
.thing:hover .thing__body {
color: red;
}
```

But now CSS is is squirreled away in each component and they don't know what is happening to their parent.

I think I'm missing a fundamental understanding of something about React, cause something so easy can't be so hard.

I've found examples of how to pass the hover state to child components... if they are explicitly included,  But what if we are just rendering {props.children}

```
//This is just pseudo code, to get the question across
//We are trying to render TestComp
const TestComp = () => {
  return (
    <Thing>
      <Title>Title</Title>
      <Body>Title</Body>
    </Thing>
  );
};

const Thing = (props) => {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
  //Thing doesn't know the particular components that are going to be in it.
  //It just renders children, but i would like those children to be aware of the hover 
  //state on this Thing component
  return (<div className="thing" onMouseOver={setHover(true)}>
      {props.children}
      <style jsx>{``}</style>
    </div>);
};
const Body = (props) => {
  //HOW DO I....
  //I would like this text to be red when thing is hovered on...
  //I'm not sure how you pass state down from Thing since Thing doesnt 
  //explicitly render this
  return (
    <div className="thing__body">
      {props.children}

      <style jsx>{`
        .thing__body {
          color: black;
        } 
        .thing__body--hover {
          color: red;
        }
      `}</style>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use `React.cloneElement` to update the props of the children.  I put together a [quick example](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-leaf-5tp25?file=/src/App.js:65-663) based upon your code.

```
const Body = ({ hover }) => (
  <div
    style={{
      width: "50px",
      height: "50px",
      backgroundColor: hover ? "red" : "blue"
    }}
  >
    Child!
  </div>
);

const Thing = ({ children }) => {
  const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
  const childrenArray = React.Children.toArray(children);

  return (
    <div
      className="thing"
      onMouseOver={() => setHover(true)}
      onMouseOut={() => setHover(false)}
    >
      {childrenArray.map(child => React.cloneElement(child, { hover }))}
    </div>
  );
};

const TestComp = () => (
  <Thing>
    <Body />
  </Thing>
);
```

We clone the existing `Body` component and modify the props object to include our `hover` prop.  Make sure you use `React.Children.toArray` to make sure you are working with an array of children, otherwise things might not work out as expected.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by pulling the hoverstate into the parent.  I passed the setter to the component I want to watch for a hover on, and i pass the state of that hover to the child i want to update.

```
const TestComp = () => {
  const [hover,setHover] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Thing handleHover={setHover}>
      <Title>Title</Title>
      <Body isHovering={hover}>Title</Body>
    </Thing>
  );
};
```

Comment: I definitely think this is what you were intending to do from the start, as cloning elements to override props is almost never necessary.  However, this doesn't answer your question.  You may want to consider updating the question to reflect your intent.  More of a "I want this specific result, how?" as opposed to "I want to do things in this specific way, how?"  Glad you figured out your issue!